# Loading local shared libraries in gdb

Tags: gdb, shared-objects

I would have thought this question was already asked, but I couldn't find it. Bear with me if it was.

I am trying out modifications to an existing program in a debian installation.

The program, call it foo, when compiled creates some of it's own shared libraries. I would like to debug the program and step into one of the  local shared libraries, call it libbar.so.

However since this is an existing program there is already a /usr/lib/libbar.so, which I do not want to overwrite.

So how do I get gdb to use the local libbar.so?

Answer (score 1):

> The program, call it foo, when compiled creates some of it's own shared libraries.

Do you mean that the program, at runtime, writes out to disk its own copy of `libbar.so`?

That is highly unusual. What you probably mean is that when *building* the program, a local `libbar.so` is also built.

> I would like to debug the program and step into one of the local shared libraries, call it libbar.so.

This should already be happening if in fact the program loaded local `libbar.so`.

What's probably happening is that when you run the program, *it* loads `/usr/lib/libbar.so`, and then GDB uses what the program has already loaded (you can see what GDB believes is loaded by using `info shared` GDB command).

If you want your program to load local copy of `libbar.so`, you need to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or modify the `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` baked into the program, using `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib` (where the local `libbar.so` is located in `/path/to/lib/libbar.so`). Once you do that, GDB will automatically pick up the local `libbar.so`.